# Search one Cell in a whole column (Foundry Contour)

Tags: palantir-foundry

I need to eliminate some rows in my data:
example
I have a Cost Center and a Partner Cost Center. But if the Partner Cost Center is somewhere in the column Cost Center available i need to eliminate this row. how can i do this?

i tried it with the "WHEN" expression but this is not including all cells of the "Cost Center" column.

does anyone know how to solve this problem?

thanks

I tried it with

Case
When (Cost Center) = (Partner Cost Center) Then "cancel"
Else "keep"
End

but this only works if the Cost Center and Partner Cost Center is equal in the same row. but i need it when the partner Cost Center is also available in another row of the Cost Center column

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 columns (A and B) and you want to keep only the rows were A cannot be found in B.

An approach that should work:

- Inner join on A and B (you get all the rows that matches, so those you need to eliminate) - Join board in Contour - `Intersection` operation
- Remove the rows that were matched, to keep only the "others" - Union board in Contour - `Remove Rows` operation

https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/contour/boards-join/